# After the vue project is packaged, the css style attribute value of a certain line is lost

Tags: sass, vuejs2, vue-cli-3, sass-loader

**Background：**

In the vue project, sass syntax is used，There is a vue file containing the following code，The effects are different after local preview and packaged release.

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(red 0px 1px, transparent 0px 2px) 40px 0px/1px 100% no-repeat;
```

**Local browser f12 preview：**
[image]

**After executing the npm run build command：**
[image]

As you can see, the "0" after "red" is lost, How to solve this problem?

Thanks!